# creating payment method on stripe google pay after every transaction whatever card is same or not in react native

Tags: android, react-native, stripe-payments, google-pay

I integrated google pay using @stripe/stripe-react-native library in react native project all working fine but it is creating payment method after every transaction whatever card is same or not.

```
    if (!(await isGooglePaySupported({ testEnv: envTest }))) {
      Alert.alert('Google Pay is not supported.');
      return;
    }
    const { error } = await initGooglePay({
      testEnv: envTest,
      merchantName: 'app',
      countryCode: props.datum.twoLetterCountryCode,
      billingAddressConfig: {
        format: 'FULL',
        isPhoneNumberRequired: false,
        isRequired: false,
      },
      existingPaymentMethodRequired: false,
      isEmailRequired: false,
    });
    if (error) {
      // Alert.alert(error.code, error.message);
      console.log(error.message);
      return;
    } else {
      console.log('Google Pay Init Sucessfully...!')
    }
  }, []);
  const fetchPaymentIntentClientSecret = async () => {
    createPaymentMethod();
  };



    const createPaymentMethod = async () => {
    
    const { error, paymentMethod } = await createGooglePayPaymentMethod({
      amount: Number(total),
      currencyCode: props.datum.Currency,
    });
    console.log('Payment Method: ' + JSON.stringify(paymentMethod));

    if (error) {
      Alert.alert(error.code, error.message);
      props.nav.navigate('HomeScreen');
    } else if (paymentMethod) {
      
      props.datum.PType = 'googlepay-' + pMethod.Card.brand;
      props.datum.Cardholder = pMethod.billingDetails.name == null ? 'Card Name not available!' : pMethod.billingDetails.name; // should be changed to paymentMethod.billingDetails.name after testing...
      props.datum.CardNum = pMethod.Card.last4;
      props.datum.CardExpireMonth = pMethod.Card.expMonth;
      props.datum.CardExpireYear = pMethod.Card.expYear;
      props.datum.PaymentToken = pMethod.id;
      props.datum.GoogleAppleToken = '';

      makePaymentAPI(props.datum)
        .then(async (r) => {
          if (r.Status == 'Success') {
            var clientSecret1 = r.ClientSecret;
            return clientSecret1;
          }
          else {
            props.nav.navigate('HomeScreen');
          }
        })
        .catch((e) => {
          Alert.alert('Payment Failed', e);
          props.nav.navigate('HomeScreen');
        });
    }
  };
    

 const pay = async () => {
        const clientSecret = await fetchPaymentIntentClientSecret();

        const { error } = await presentGooglePay({
          clientSecret,
          forSetupIntent: false,
        });
    
        if (error.stripeErrorCode) {
          Alert.alert(error.code, error.message);

          props.nav.navigate('HomeScreen');
        }else{
          props.nav.navigate('Thankyou');
        }

      };
```

If I am trying to store Payment method on first transaction in async storage and then making payment using google it's not open google pay module, it directs deduct payment from stripe and not opening module of google pay please help.

Comment: After google pay is saved a payment method, it will be treated like a normal card. For future charges, payment will be deducted directly without going through Google Pay.